# Redirect at first login in Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

```
Good morning,
```

I can't do a redirect on the first wordpress login for clients,
I created a "has_not_logged_in_yet" field on the database,
but when I go to do an update, the update_user_meta function with this "woocommerce_login_redirect" hook doesn't work.
If I use "init" as a hook, update_user_meta works but the redirect doesn't work.
I am attaching the code,
you can help me? Thank you!

```
function after_user_register( $user_id ){
    add_user_meta($user_id, "has_not_logged_in_yet", "true", true);
    }
add_action( 'user_register', 'after_user_register', 10, 1 );

function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    $role = $user->roles[0];
    $id= $user->ID;
    $dashboard = admin_url();
    $catalogo = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );        
    $changePWeAddress = get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Conferma Indirizzo' ) );
    if ( $role == 'customer' ) {
      $user_meta=get_user_meta($id);
      if($user_meta['has_not_logged_in_yet'][0] == "true"){
          update_user_meta($user_id, "has_not_logged_in_yet","false");
          $redirect = $changePWeAddress;
          }
          else
          $redirect =   $catalogo;
          }
          return $redirect
          }
          
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several `syntax` errors. I have revised your code. Also, you are passing `$user_id` variable to `update_user_meta`

**Replace**

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, "has_not_logged_in_yet","false" );
```

**With this**

```
update_user_meta( $id, "has_not_logged_in_yet","false" );
```

**Complete Code**

```
function after_user_register( $user_id ){
    add_user_meta( $user_id, "has_not_logged_in_yet", "true", true );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'after_user_register', 10, 1 );

function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {

    $role             = $user->roles[0];
    $id               = $user->ID;
    $dashboard        = admin_url();
    $catalogo         = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );        
    $changePWeAddress = get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Conferma Indirizzo' ) );

    if ( $role == 'customer' ) {
        $user_meta = get_user_meta($id);
        if( $user_meta['has_not_logged_in_yet'][0] == "true" ){
            update_user_meta( $id, "has_not_logged_in_yet","false" );
            $redirect = $changePWeAddress;
        } else{
            $redirect = $catalogo;
        }
        return $redirect;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```